# how to implement a service in the server and connect it to the client (Blazor hosted Webassembly)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor

I have a blazor hosted webassemly project and I want to implement a service that sends an email to the user in my server and then somehow connect it to the client and call it from there. I'm not really sure how the communication between the client and the server works, so I was wondering if someone could give me a direction.

Comment: What do you mean by "and then somehow connect it to the client and call it from there".. Usually wasm client communicate with server part using web api. But could be also SignalR, which may be a perfect fit for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Communication from client to server is usually done via an API call. That call can return a response that the client uses.

For communication initiated by the server, you'd need SignalR, which was designed for exactly this sort of scenario.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer i was reading stuff about SignalR and tried some things. I could eventually figure it out and it works. But could you please  show me what an api call would look like. For example I used the code from this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KngjMHzcz6E) to send an email, but it works only for Blazor Server app, so I wanted to make it work for webassembly.

Comment: The API call can look however you want, it's just a plain HTTP request. Have a look at minimal API in ASP.NET, it is what is (usually) used with Blazor WebAsm, and should be all you need.